# One colorbar for two imshows

Tags: python, subplot, colorbar, imshow

i have the following code and somehow i can not place the colorbar in such a place that it is not overlapping with the imshow itself and if I place it further outside it is cutted off :(
I tried already a lot of things, but nothing worked for this problem.
If the colorbar is not horizontal that would work for me, too, but then the label of the axis need to be perpendicular too.

HELP

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vegetables = [ "One magnet", "Two magnets","washer",
              "ST37 - 1", "ST37 - 2", "ST37 - 3", "RVS"]



farmers0 = ["1 cm/s", "1.25 cm/s"]



mask0 = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
                    [False, False, False, True, True, True, True]])

harvest1 = np.array([[ 1.9, 1.6,1.1,1.2,1.1,0.5,0.7],
                    [ 1.6, 0.8,0.9, 0,0,0,0]])

harvest1 = np.ma.array(harvest1, mask=mask0)

harvest2 = np.array([[ 0.9, 1.0,0.7,1.0,1.1,0.4,0.6],
                    [ 0.9, 0.8,0.8, 0,0,0,0]])
harvest2 = np.ma.array(harvest2, mask=mask0)




fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=False)



im0 = ax[0].imshow(harvest1, cmap='RdYlGn_r', vmin = 0.5, vmax = 1.65)

# We want to show all ticks...
ax[0].set_xticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)))
ax[0].set_yticks(np.arange(len(farmers0)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax[0].set_xticklabels(vegetables)
ax[0].set_yticklabels(farmers0)


# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")



for i in range(len(farmers0)):
    for j in range(len(vegetables)):
        text = ax[0].text(j, i, harvest1[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="k")
    

im0 = ax[1].imshow(harvest2, cmap='RdYlGn_r', vmin = 0.5, vmax = 1.65)

# We want to show all ticks...
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)))
ax[1].set_yticks(np.arange(len(farmers0)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax[1].set_xticklabels(vegetables)
ax[1].set_yticklabels(farmers0)


# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")



for i in range(len(farmers0)):
    for j in range(len(vegetables)):
        text = ax[1].text(j, i, harvest2[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="k")
 
#fig.colorbar(im0, ax=ax.ravel().tolist(), orientation = 'horizontal')



#plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(top=1.5)

fig.tight_layout()

cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.9,0.82,0.05]) #links, hight
#cax = divider.append.axes("bottom", size= "5%", pad = 0.05)
bar2 = plt.colorbar(im0, cax = cbaxes , orientation = 'horizontal')

bar2.ax.set_title('90 % confidence interval of $d$')



plt.show()
```

Comment: something like this?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847146/9703451

Comment: Well kind of, but i do not know how to implement it to my probelm, because i use the axes differently.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer that should solve your problem here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a version that uses `GridSpec` to get more control over the axis-grid  (e.g. so you can adjust the spacing between colorbar and axes etc.)

also note that i use `aspect='auto'` in the `ax.imshow` calls to allow non-square pixels!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec, GridSpecFromSubplotSpec

vegetables = [ "One magnet", "Two magnets","washer",
              "ST37 - 1", "ST37 - 2", "ST37 - 3", "RVS"]



farmers0 = ["1 cm/s", "1.25 cm/s"]



mask0 = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
                    [False, False, False, True, True, True, True]])

harvest1 = np.array([[ 1.9, 1.6,1.1,1.2,1.1,0.5,0.7],
                    [ 1.6, 0.8,0.9, 0,0,0,0]])

harvest1 = np.ma.array(harvest1, mask=mask0)

harvest2 = np.array([[ 0.9, 1.0,0.7,1.0,1.1,0.4,0.6],
                    [ 0.9, 0.8,0.8, 0,0,0,0]])
harvest2 = np.ma.array(harvest2, mask=mask0)


# -----------------------------------------------
# manually create an axes to have full control over spacing etc.
gs = GridSpec(2, 1, 
              height_ratios=(.5, 9.5))
gs_ax = GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, gs[1], 
                                hspace=.5)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = []
ax.append(fig.add_subplot(gs_ax[0]))
ax.append(fig.add_subplot(gs_ax[1]))

cbaxes = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

# manually ensure that x- and y- axes are shared
ax[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(ax[1])
ax[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(ax[1])
# -----------------------------------------------

im0 = ax[0].imshow(harvest1, cmap='RdYlGn_r', vmin = 0.5, vmax = 1.65,
                   aspect="auto")

# We want to show all ticks...
ax[0].set_xticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)))
ax[0].set_yticks(np.arange(len(farmers0)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax[0].set_xticklabels(vegetables)
ax[0].set_yticklabels(farmers0)


# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")



for i in range(len(farmers0)):
    for j in range(len(vegetables)):
        text = ax[0].text(j, i, harvest1[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="k")
    

im0 = ax[1].imshow(harvest2, cmap='RdYlGn_r', vmin = 0.5, vmax = 1.65,
                   aspect="auto")

# We want to show all ticks...
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)))
ax[1].set_yticks(np.arange(len(farmers0)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax[1].set_xticklabels(vegetables)
ax[1].set_yticklabels(farmers0)


# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")



for i in range(len(farmers0)):
    for j in range(len(vegetables)):
        text = ax[1].text(j, i, harvest2[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="k")
 

#cax = divider.append.axes("bottom", size= "5%", pad = 0.05)
bar2 = plt.colorbar(im0, cax = cbaxes , orientation = 'horizontal')

bar2.ax.set_title('90 % confidence interval of $d$')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sry for the late answer, thank you sooo much, this works perfectly. i just will play around with it, but I am very happy now :D

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

matplotlib actually warns you that `tight_layout` will not work with manually added axes...

> UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
> fig.tight_layout()

use `fig.subplots_adjust` to set the boundaries of your plot manually!

so basically... just add this line at the very end and you're fine :-)

```py
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
```

and maybe also explicitly specify the figure-size by changing your call to `plt.subplots` to:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(7, 5), sharex=True, sharey=False)
```

[image]

Comment: This I already tried, but then the buttom gets cut off

Comment: well... first of all `subplots_adjust` also accepts a `bottom=0.2` argument... but the easiest way is to just keep the call to `fig.tight_layout()` and then only adjust the top afterwards

Comment: that looks very wierd, the imshow is somehow cutted off

Comment: I've added the image I get when executing the code with my adjustments... there's nothing cut off at all

Comment: For me it doesn't look at all like this, I have even spacing between the plots

Comment: well, that's strange... I've just copy-pasted your code and added `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)`  what matplotlib-version are you using?

Comment: I have python 3.6.7

Comment: i ment the matplotlib-version but nevermind, i don't think that's the problem here... I'd suggest you add the following to your `plt.subplots` call:  `figsize=(7, 5)`  and try again

Comment: It still does not work, do you think it could help to implement the colorbar as a third subplot?

Comment: I think the best way would be to already start with a grid of 3 axes!   give me a moment I'll add a basic example how that would work