# Matplotlib imshow with x values log-spaced but y values lin-spaced

Tags: python, matplotlib

## Task

I have a grid of values `zs` relating to some `xs` values that are log-spaced, and `ys` values that are lin-spaced. I tried to make it work as follows but the plot looks weird.
The key problem is that the x-values are in the log-space and the y values are not.

I tried using `ax.set_xscale('log')` but doesn't seem to do the job. I am not even sure if this is possible, since it's just a grid.

## Minimal Working Example

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng

# x values are log-spaced, y values are lin-spaced
xs = np.geomspace(0.001, 1.0, num=20, endpoint=True)
ys = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num=20, endpoint=False)

# Generate z-values randomly for the MWE
zs = np.zeros((20, 20))
rng = default_rng(seed=1234)
for x_ix in range(len(xs)):
    for y_ix in range(len(ys)):
        zs[x_ix, y_ix] = rng.normal()

fig, ax = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5))
im = ax.imshow(zs, origin='lower')
ax.set_xticks(xs[::4])
ax.set_xticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(x) for x in xs[::4]], fontsize=8)
ax.set_yticks(ys[::4]) 
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:.1f}".format(y) for y in ys[::4]], fontsize=8)
ax.cax.colorbar(im)
ax.cax.toggle_label(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Alternative - `pcolor`

Following the suggestion, I have coded it as follows.

```py
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 5))
im = ax.pcolor(x_grid, y_grid, zs)
ax.set_xscale('log')
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

This works well, only problem is that in practice I have 5 plots in a row and the colorbar is taking the space off the final plot. Basically I am actually using `plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(18, 5))` but then when I add the colorbar, the final plot is less wide than the others because it contains the colorbar

Comment: `imshow` only works with linear axes.  You can try `pcolormesh` instead.

Comment: Ahh I've got a partial solution with `pcolor`. I'm gonna write it now

Comment: @JohanC I have added a partial solution. I added another question underneath it because i am not sure how to deal with the colorbar when I have multiple plots in a row. I know it's a different question, but would you have any suggestion?

Comment: Usually, people create 6 subplots, the last one narrower to be used for the colorbar.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447352/single-colorbar-for-two-subplots-changes-the-size-of-one-of-the-subplots or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845186/putting-one-color-bar-for-several-subplots-from-different-dataframes